# copy several excel files from Server 1 to server 2 with powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to copy several excel files from Server 1 to server 2 with powershell

The excel files have the following format on the source server

```
User_20190720132901.csv
User_20190720133205.csv
User_20190720134007.csv
```

Explanation of the naming format:
for example `User_20190720132900.csv`

2019 stands for the year
07 stands for month
20 stands for day
13 stands for hour
29 stands for minutes
01 stands for second

I have tried to test with the following code. I got the following error:

> ```
> + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (CloseBraceToken:TokenId) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace
> ```

I have more than one csv file on my source.
How can I define a source that takes the naming format in considerations?

```
$source="D:\mysource\User_20190720132901.csv" 

$destination = "E:\mydestination\User_20190720132901.csv"


foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem $source)) {
If ($item.LastWriteTime -lt ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1))) {

Copy-Item $item.FullName $destination

}
```

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for your code and error messages (indent 4 spaces). 2) I would consider using `robocopy` rather than trying to write a script.

Comment: Can you give me an example based on my problem? I am using scripts because a job have to run the scripts once every day on a windows platform.

Comment: The `robocopy` command has a number of command-line options that direct its behavior. Type `robocopy /?` for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$source` and `$destination` variabless should contain folder names, not the full path and nanme of a single file.

Next, it is unclear why he date format in the file name should be important as you are using the `LastWriteTime` property..

```
$source      = 'D:\mysource'      # $source and $destination are folders
$destination = 'D:\mydestination'
$refDate     = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

# if the destination folder does not exist, create it first
if (!(Test-Path -Path $destination -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
}
```

Now use the LastWriteTime property of the file to determine if it needs to be copied or not.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter 'User_*.csv' -File | 
    Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '(\d{14})$'} |
    ForEach-Object {
        # test if the file is older than yesterday ($refDate)
        If ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate) {
            $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $destination -Force -WhatIf
        } 
    }
```

**OR**

Get the date from the file's name and use that

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter 'User_*.csv' -File | 
    Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '(\d{14})$'} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $fileDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[1], 'yyyyMMddHHmmss', $null)
        # test if the date from the file name is older than yesterday ($refDate)
        If ($fileDate -lt $refDate) {
            $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $destination -Force -WhatIf
        } 
    }
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` switch if you are satisfied with the results

Comment: I got the following errors. Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:14 char:27
+ $_ | Copy-Item <<<<  -Destination $destination -Force -WhatIf
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Comment: using get the date from the file's name. I got the following errors: Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.
At line:9 char:55
+ Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter 'User_*.csv' -File <<<<  | 
+ CategoryInfo: InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: @Joe, it seems you're on PowerShell version 2.. Take away the `-File` and add `Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer}`

Comment: @Joe In the first code I forgot a pipe symbol. Fixed that now.

Comment: You are correct, I am on PowerShell version 2. -File was removed. Then i got the following errors: Get-ChildItem : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Where-Object'.
At line:9 char:14
+ Get-ChildItem <<<<  -Path $source -Filter 'User_*.csv' Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer}| 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: @Joe you forgot to put a pipe symbol `|` before the `Where-Object`

Comment: I have now do the same test on Powershell version 5. The file from D:\myspurce was not copied to my d:\mydestinatin. I got following when the scripts was run: What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\mysource\User_Block1_20190725132900.csv Destination: D:\mydestination\User_Block1_20190725132900
.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\mysource\User_Block1_20190725132900.csv Destination: D:\mydestination\User_Block1_20190725132900.csv". Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have now tried it on Powershell version 2 (a pipe symbol was put before the where-object). I am getting the same result as version 5. The files was not copied but the 2 .csv files i was twstin´g with was not copied: I got following: What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\mysource\User_Block1_20190725132900.csv Destination: D:\mydestination\User_Block1_20190725132900
.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\mysource\User_Block2_20190725102900.csv Destination: D:\mydestination\User_Block1_20190725132900.csv".

Comment: Hello Theo, It works when I removed WHATIF on both Powershell version 2 and 5.Thanks a lot for your help.I really appreciate all the hard work you've done to help. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Joe Glad it works for you Please consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark icon next to it.This will also help others to find it more easily.